# Who would buy my bitcoin? (Hypothetical question)

Tags: sell-bitcoins, taxes

Lets say if 1 BTC = $1000USD tomorrow and I have around 1000 BTC, how would I sell my 1000 BTC to put $1,000,000USD in my bank account?

Even a better hypothetical question.

If I go back in time and buy 10,000 bitcoins for half a dollar (USD) back in 2009 and wish to cash it on 2013 when 1BTC was around a grand, whom or how would I sell all my BTCs to get the maximum profit? How much should I have paid in taxes?

Comment: If you actually want to sell a sizable chunk of bitcoins, you should read into OTC markets. Hypothetical questions often veer into the "subjective" territory, which we don't really cater to here on the site. However, I've answered a somewhat similar question here: [The Scenario is confused, because it assumes that there is only one side to a trade.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/37224/5406)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of exchangers have such liquidity but you will encounter issues with withdrawal limits depending on your verification level. Also I don't think you can expect transfers of that magnitude to happen at once - they will likely chunk it out by agreeing it with you.

As for the tax, it all depends where you live as I believe you will be taxed on income.

We all wish we could go back in time - however you have to look to the future, what tells you 1 Bitcoin won't be worth $100,000 in 5 years time?